# sending hex and ascii values using python module serial

Tags: python

I am trying to send a command to a lighting device.

The command below works in the hyper term.

```
\05387988c2g<CR>
```

- `\` is an ascii character
- `g<CR>` is at the end of every command
- `g` is the acknowledgement key and `<CR>` is the carriage return

I have tried sending this command using Python's Serial Module in the code below, but it does not work because `\` is an ascii character and `g` and `<CR>` are strings that need to be at the end of the command.

Could someone tell me what command I have to send. Any help is appreciated.Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its not really clear what you expect to send ... but assuming I understand this may help.

use r"" which will consider everything to be literal (including \)... additionally you may need to send  a carriage return (\r)

```
conn.write(r'\05387988c2g')
conn.write('\r')#may or may not be needed or some other ending character
```